# Website Cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have made a wordpress website [Here](http://easy-avenues.rocketmediamodular.co.uk/) but my client asked me to write a section on our cookie policy page about what cookies the CMS use. I have used firebug to look at the cookies and none show. Is this normal / Correct? I would have thought Wordpress would have used some cookies as default.

To note: Users don't login to the site. Logins are just for administration.

Thanks in Advance

Ian

Answer (score 1):

[As stated on WordPress' documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies), a "fresh" WordPress instance (without any plugin) will only offer a session cookie to the user if he reaches the CMS login page (`wp-login.php` / `/wp-admin/`). This cookie being used only for authentication purpose, [you don't need to ask for user's consent](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm#section_2).

It should be noted that external scripts (ads, tracking) and WordPress plugins can also define cookies, so you should make sure to review them before writing the cookie policy.